# how to make chart column with drill down with D3 Js

Tags: d3.js

Could some one please suggest how to do column-drilldown with D3 JS library,

below example is from Hightchart,

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-drilldown

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried google it? Checked other questions on SO? Checked the examples found on d3:s homepage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A complete code example for this problem is probably quite extensive, so I'll mostly keep to how you would approach it and assume you know enough of D3 to turn the concept into code.

Lets assume you have the functionality for drawing a general bar chart.

Part of that functionality would priobably be things like

1. Setting up your svg element and containers
2. Setting up your scales (one for x and one for y)
3. Adding axes based on the scales you have created
4. Adding your bars to the svg container
   4.1 Make sure you have your data set available as an array
   4.2 Create an enter selection for the available data and append `rect`elements
   4.3 Update attributes like `x`, `y` for all your available bar nodes
   4.4 Remove any nodes on your exit selection

Voila you have a simple bar chart. Nothing new in that and you can have a look at the code details here -> https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304

Now in order to do the drill down:
In order to avoid lots of code repetition it probably makes sense to separate the above steps into functions. So for example a setup function that just creates your svg and containers as well as your scales.

Important about the setup function is that you do not need to rerun it on drill through.

Second you will want an `update` function. This contains steps 3+, which you will need to rerun in order to update your charts on drill through.

One addition here would be adding functionality for updating your scale domain in the beginning (as your data changes on drill through and you want to reflect that in your scales).

Now that you have those two functions all you really need to do is:

Add a click handler to your axis labels or your bars (click on bars might be easier for now). You cans use d3's `.on()` function for that.
In that event you will want to subset your data by the value of the clicked bar (or get a new data set for the bar value depending on how your data is structured) and then run the update function we created above with the new data.

It could look something like this:

```
d3.selectAll('.bar-nodes')
    .on('click', function(d) {
        var updatedData = updateData(d);
        updateChart(updatedData);
    });
```

If anything is unclear some more specific questions would be good.
Hope that helps.